# How can I define an attribute which can contain *either* an IDREF or a string enumeration?

Tags: attributes, xsd

I've made a simple UI definition language for a project and now want to create a schema, for ease of validation.  Unfortunately, my XSD skills are *quite* rusty, and I find myself trying to so something that I'm not even certain is possible.

The UI is made up of "blocks" which can be positioned in relation to one another.  In order to simplify the most common use cases, I'd like the referencing attribute to be able to contain any of the strings `parent`, `previous`, or `next`.  In order to be as flexible as possible, I'd also like it to be able to point to any element with an ID.

In other words, I'd like the following to be valid:

```
<ui>
    <block id="foo"/>
    <block/>
    <block anchor="previous"/>
    <block anchor="#foo"/>
</ui>
```

How can I describe this in XSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, XSD contains a feature which does exactly this — combines two or more types — and I had simply missed it.  A `union` creates a type whose lexical space covers the lexical spaces of all of its member types (in other words, it can contain a value matching any of its subtypes).

With the caveat that `IDREF`s cannot contain a leading `#` (it's a direct reference to an ID, not a fragment identifier for a URL), the following schema will validate the example XML.  The interesting bits are `AnchorType` and `TreeReferenceType`.

```
<schema targetNamespace="urn:x-ample:ui" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ui="urn:x-ample:ui">
    <element name="ui" type="ui:UIType"/>

    <complexType name="UIType">
        <sequence>
            <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="block" type="ui:BlockType"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>

    <complexType name="BlockType">
        <attribute use="optional" name="id" type="ID"/>
        <attribute name="anchor" type="ui:AnchorType"/>
    </complexType>

    <simpleType name="AnchorType">
        <union memberTypes="ui:TreeReferenceType IDREF"/>
    </simpleType>

    <simpleType name="TreeReferenceType">
        <restriction base="string">
            <enumeration value="parent"/>
            <enumeration value="previous"/>
            <enumeration value="next"/>
        </restriction>
    </simpleType>
</schema>
```